# Geo Fencing Code - pure SQL server 2008 implemenation

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need help with this.  I am looking for a complete TSQL code.  (no c++/C#)

1. define 32 points around a central point forming a quasi circle with a given radius in miles.
2. Check the 32 above points against a given point to see if it is included inside the geo-fence.

Thanks 
JJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into using [SQL Server 2008's spatial types, specifically geometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280487.aspx). To do what you're asking, you would do the following:

1. Create a point using [STGeomFromText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933823.aspx).
2. Buffer your point using [STBuffer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933963.aspx) to create a circle.
3. Use [STIntersects()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933899.aspx) to determine if other points are within your circle.